# Difference between "jquery Load" and "direct url loading" of an aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, url, page-lifecycle

I have two web pages: MainPage.aspx and ChildPage.aspx.

what is the difference(if any) when Child page is loaded using

1. URL - `http://localhost:3733/jqueryMenu/ChildPage.aspx`
2. jquery load used in Main Page - `$('div').load("ChildPage.aspx");`

Is there any difference in page life cycle or anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. **First** will be `redirected` to `browser` and whole content will be `shown in browser`,
2. **Second one** will load your page data to `div` which uses [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) so if you want to show only the content to `specific div` then you can use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: this difference I understand. I want to know if there is any difference in "the way ChildPage loads or if the events will trigger in different ways" in these cases.